# Index on a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, topology, chern-simons-theory

How can the integral of a topological term (like the Nieh-Yan term) on all of a compact manifold be nonzero whereas it's a total derivative and the manifold has no boundary?
I assume the manifold can be covered with one coordinate patch.
I am specifically considering the index for chiral anomaly on a compact manifold.
I think if the manifold can not be covered with one coordinate patch we would have to calculate the integral on different patchs separately and the result will be an integral over boundaries of different patchs.
I just hope to understand why my intuition is wrong.

Comment: Can you give some context for the term "topological integral"? A cursory search brings up almost nothing, except that the term is sometimes synonymous with "winding number".

Comment: 1. There are plenty of different "topological integrals", and the integral itself is not a derivative (the result of an integral is just a number). Are you referring to the integrand of the Chern number $\int \mathrm{Tr}(F^k)$ being the derivative of the k-th Chern-Simons form? If so, please clarify that in your question. (Note that saying "for instance $R\wedge R$" is rather unclear without saying what $R$ is or where the integral is...)

Comment: 2. Please also clarify what you mean by "coordinate patch" and why it is relevant here. The torus is not diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence is not "covered with one coordinate patch" in the common sense where we define a coordinate chart to be a diffeomorphism from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an open subset of the manifold.

Comment: What does the word "it" in the phrase "it's a total derivative" refer to?

Comment: "it" referes to the integrand (i.e. the Nieh yan term that can be written as d(e^a\wedge T_a)).

Comment: Related Math.SE post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939773/11127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nieh-yan three-form  is $N=d({\bf e}^{*a}\wedge T_a)$ where ${\bf e}^{*a}\wedge T_a$ is *globally defined* --- i.e on the overlap of coordinate patches it is the same scalar-valued 3-form in both patches. Consquently  on a closed 4 manifold $M$ we have 
$$
\int_M N= \int_{\partial N}{\bf e}^{*a}\wedge T_a=0
$$
because $\partial M=\emptyset$.   On the other hand 
$
 F^2=d CS $ where the Chern-Simons form $CS$  is not gauge invariant and so *not* globally defined. When we  have to use several patches there are contributions form the differences btween CS in one one gauge patch and CS in the other patch in the  overlap and so  we can have $\int_M F^2\ne0$.

Incidently there are papers in which $\int_M N\ne 0$ but then either $M$ has a boundary or the  chosen vierbein field $e^{*a}$ is singular.